# CDB doesn't show the line of code as WinDBG does for callstacks

Tags: windbg, postmortem-debugging

I am using WinDBG 6.12.0002.633 X86.

I'm having an issue with the command-line debugger CDB not showing the same results as WinDBG for the `k` and `kL` commands.

In WinDBG, the `k` command correctly shows the line of code for the callstack where the `kL` command correctly strips that information and only shows the offset.

```
1:128:armce> k
Child-SP RetAddr  Call Site
761efaf4 78013cdc module_78010000!SomeModule::Foo+0xb4 [bar.cpp @ 268]

1:128:armce> kL
Child-SP RetAddr  Call Site
761efaf4 78013cdc module_78010000!SomeModule::Foo+0xb4
```

In CDB, the results of the `k` and `kL` are identical:

```
1:128:armce> k
Child-SP RetAddr  Call Site
761efaf4 78013cdc module_78010000!SomeModule::Foo+0xb4

1:128:armce> kL
Child-SP RetAddr  Call Site
761efaf4 78013cdc module_78010000!SomeModule::Foo+0xb4
```

What can I do to get CDB to show the line of code for the `k` command as WinDBG does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running the command ".lines" to cause line information to be loaded. WinDBG defaults to line information being loaded, CDB and NTSD do not.